# swift ios get file path for imageView

Tags: ios, swift, file, gallery, filepath

I have already copy the file absolute path and paste in simulator browser, the image can be opened. But the fileExists is fail, i dont know why..... Can anyone help

```
 let defaultImage = "302C3FA1-E4E1-4CD8-B6DF-2FF4E4E24C11.jpeg"

loadImage(at: defaultImage)
```

```
 func fileExists(at path: String) -> Bool {
        return FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path)
    }

    func loadImage(at path: String) -> UIImage? {
        let tempPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
        let imagePath = "\(tempPath)\(path.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))"
        guard fileExists(at: imagePath) else { return nil }
        guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) else { return nil }
        return image
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need split filename and extension filename.

If you use main bundle. you can follow this code

```
let stringPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "your_filename", ofType: "txt")

let urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "your_filename", withExtension: "txt")
```

or you can use my code.

```
func readConfigFromBundle(fileExtension: String) -> TCBConfigure? {
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    
    if let resPath = bundle.resourcePath {
        do {
            let dirContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: resPath)
            let filteredFiles = dirContents.filter { $0.contains(fileExtension) }
            for fileName in filteredFiles {
                let sourceURL = bundle.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                let data: NSData? = NSData.init(contentsOf: sourceURL)
                if let fileData = data {
                    // implement your logic
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // implement when error
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I want to get image from gallery.  and try to add file path to my imageview